# 'odata.nextLink'-error in SendMail via Graph-Library

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I wanted to continue with a simple SendMail-example that worked a few weeks ago.
I have only updated the NuGet-Packages and now it fails.
(This uses Microsoft.Graph, .Graph.Core, .Identity.Client and dependencies, >20 in total)

Authentication works fine, I can query a user.

```
    ...
    var u = await graphServiceClient.Users["myname@company.de"].Request().GetAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"okay, user = {u.DisplayName}"); // this works

    var M = new Message();
    M.Subject = "Graph Library Test";
    M.ToRecipients = new Recipient[] 
        { new Recipient() { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress() { Address = "myname@company.de" } } };
    string htmlBody = @"<div>Test-Message</div>";
    M.Body = new ItemBody() { ContentType = BodyType.Html, Content = htmlBody };
    await graphServiceClient.Users["abc@company.de"].SendMail(M, false).Request().PostAsync();
```

This error occurs at the SendMail-line:

> -- ERROR --
> Code: RequestBodyRead Message: The 'odata.nextLink' instance or property annotation has a null value. In OData, the
> 'odata.nextLink' instance or property annotation must have a non-null
> string value.

All I found on this is that 'nextLink' seems to be associated with paging in requests, but nothing that provides any help.

Comment: Having the same issue. no solution so far.

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? Also, are you experiencing the same behavior with Graph Explorer/Postman?

Comment: The issue happened after updating Graph SDK beta from 4.7.0-preview to 4.8.0-preview. I Reverted to 4.7.0-preview.

Comment: Could you check if odata.nextLink is being sent in Additional data property?Something like this while ('yourobject'.AdditionalData["@odata.nextLink"].ToString() != null)

Comment: @Shweta .Graph 4.2.0 in my case, and 4.1.0 also works again. Sending without the library just with HttpClient also works fine.
I don't really know where to put your code. M.AdditionalData is null, and after the call to .SendMail(..).Request(), I see there is .RequestBody.Message.AdditionalData -> which is also null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue after updating Microsoft.Graph from 4.1.0 to 4.2.0 this morning. I've reverted to 4.1.0 and it's back working again.

Comment: 4.6.0 version is working fine also :)